# jQuery generate multiple arrays and generate HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have a website that where a user can browse through products in a gallery format. This  gallery will be populated using an ajax call that passes the category to a php script which then fetches all the items matching that category and echoes all the item information back. The  success function of the  ajax  call then needs to split the data and insert each  items data  into its own array that will  be used to generate the  html to display the item.

I  am  struggling with the  inserting the data into its own array part as the   amount  of items will vary depending on how many are in the database at the  moment.

Here  is  what I have  so far:

The  jQuery function:

```
$('.category').click(function() {


    var category;

    if ($(this).hasClass('Shirts')) {
        category = 'shirts';
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('Hats')) {
        category = 'hats';
    }
    if ($(this).hasClass('Acc')) {
        category = 'acc';
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'galleryfetch.php',
        data: { 'category' : category }
    }).done(function(data) {
        alert('Succes ' + data);
        var arr = data.split('#');  // Information split by #
        for (int i = 0; i < (arr.length / 4); i++) { //  arr.length divided by 4 because each item has 4 pieces of information

            // Insert each item into its own array. So the first  array will be arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3]. Second array will be  arr[4], arr[5], arr[6], arr[7]
        }

    }).fail(function(response) {
        alert('Fail' + response);
    });
});
```

Here  is the  php script:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {

    $category = $_GET['category'];

    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'Changde90', 'database');   

    $rows = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE category = '".$category."'");

    $items = '';

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rows)) {
        $itemName = $row[1];
        $itemPrice = $row[2];
        $itemImage = $row[3];
        $itemDescription = $row[4];

        $items .= $itemName.'#'.$itemPrice.'#'.$itemImage.'#'.$itemDescription.'#';
    } 

    echo $items;
}
```

Comment: is there any reason you can't just return the data in `json` format and tell jQuery to use `json` as the expected return type? MUCH easier for handling this type of data.

Comment: Really ? Theres  no reason I know of, I'll do some reading on it then

Answer (score 2):

Create the array in php like this :

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rows)) {
    $arr[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode(array("data" => $arr));
```

Then in your javascript just decode the data and use it in your code as you like it.
For example :

```
var arr = $.parseJSON(data);
arr.itemName will return the item name
arr.itemprice will return the item price
```

Remember you have use the above code inside of $.each()

Hope this helps you.

Comment: If Im correct this would only return one item's information though would it not ? I need  some way to be able to say

Comment: arr[0].itemName, arr[1].itemName etc. for each item

Comment: As I mentioned that you have to use the code inside of $.each as the parse json will return you an array

Comment: `$arr[] = $row;` adds the `$row` var as another item in the `$arr` array

Comment: $arr[] = $row; is just like array push. It keeps on adding up items in the array.

Comment: So the each statement would be something like:

Comment: var  arr = $.parseJSON(data); $(arr).each { // code; }

Comment: Yes somewhat.. It is impossible to say exactly. I have not seen your array neither the response.. So I can say that you are quite close and you can fix that. Just try.. All d best..